# Using pickle to load random forest model gives the wrong prediction

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, random-forest

I have built a random forest model using sklearn and python, and I pickled the file as 'finalizedmode.sav'. I am now trying to load the pickled model to get predictions on the first two rows of my test data, to make sure everything is working properly. When I run the model to predict the first two rows, it gives me the correct predictions, of '[1,1]'. However when I run the pickled-loaded model on those same two rows, it gives [1,2], which is wrong. I have attached the code I have used. Thank you so much!

```
sc = StandardScaler()
loaded_model = pickle.load(open('finalizedmode.sav','rb'))
data = pd.read_csv('tworows.csv')
data = data.values
index = [0,1]
newestDatasetValues = np.delete(data,index, axis = 1)
scaled_newArray = sc.fit_transform(newestDatasetValues)
prediction = loaded_model.predict(scaled_newArray)
print(prediction)
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with the `StandardScaler` object. You are refitting it (i.e. recalculating the mean and variance) on the data from `'tworows.csv'`, which I assume is not the same dataset that you used to fit the original model (and, presumably, fit another `StandardScaler`).

This means that your model is expecting data with a different scaling than what you're providing at test time.

Ideally, the `StandardScaler` should be made a part of your model, probably using a `Pipeline` [object](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html). That way, when you save and reload the model, it will keep the same scaling.

Something like:

```
# Load all data
alldata = pd.read_csv('alldata.csv').values
unscaled_alldata = np.delete(data, [0,1], axis=1) # Or similar

# Presumably you want to split off your X and y data here somehow?
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = my_splitting_func(unscaled_alldata)
# Note no scaling performed

# Create and fit model
model = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('forest', RandomForestClassifier())])
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Save model
with open('finalizedmode.sav', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(model, f)

# Reload from file
with open('finalizedmode.sav', 'rb') as f:
    loaded_model = pickle.load(f)

### DATA LOADING (without creating a new StandardScaler)
testdata = pd.read_csv('tworows.csv').values
unscaled_testdata = np.delete(testdata, [0,1], axis=1)
## Note there is no scaling here

prediction = loaded_model.predict(unscaled_testdata)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this, but am still getting the wrong results

Comment: @jack123 Could you provide an example of your data in the question, then? I'm a little uncertain exactly what you're trying to achieve with the `np.delete` stuff. Also, have you manually verified that the data you're providing to the original and loaded models is the same?

Comment: I want to pass in a csv file, convert it to a numpy array and remove the first two columns. I then want to transform it, and it should be in the same format as the model.

Comment: When I put the code from my question into my original random forest, it gives me the right results, but when I copy this exact code into a new file to load it, it is giving me an error. I believe it is because of fit, I originally fit the data on the training data, and I do not know what to fit it on in the test file.

Comment: OK, you shouldn't be `fit`-ing on anything in the testing file. The model is already fit, you only want to call `predict` to get your results. The scaling is an important part of the model setup, you shouldn't create a new scaling for your testing data. The data should undergo the same scaling at train and test time, and that scaling should **only** be based on the training data, if we're doing things properly. I have edited my answer to reflect this. An important note here, then, is that `X_train` shouldn't be scaled either. All scaling will be done by the `StandardScaler` in the `Pipeline`.

Answer (score -1):

I would highly suggest you to create a model pipeline that includes both the preprocessors and your estimator fitted, and use random seed for reproducibility purposes. Fit the pipeline then pickle the pipeline itself, then use `pipeline.predict`. This way the model will always give the same results as trained since your scaler, estimator and other preprocessors will be packed to that model since reproducibility is an important concept. Use Pipeline or make_pipeline methods of scikitlearn for this. You can find the docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html).

Comment: Can you clarify why this would help rather than simply saving the model?

Comment: scaler or estimator shouldn't be fit again because this time they will be fit differently each time. setting seeds are super important for when you're trying to reproduce your results.

Comment: the below code post by @Gebodal would work just fine, try setting a seed.

Comment: I just realized as it was said, you're fitting the scaler twice. You have to save your scaler inside the model aswell and to do this, you have to use a pipeline. The scaler used to produce your pipeline and the second scaler you've put in your code are different.